# Hero Webpart Not Editable SHAREPOINT ONLINE

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365-developer, communication-site

I just created a communication site. By default a Hero webpart is on the main page. I can go to edit the page and on that specific webpart it gives me the option to edit details(the icon with the little pencil appears when i hover a panel). From there i can add images, texts and URLs for links etc.

That all works well and fine. The problem is when I create a new page in the communication site and add a hero web-part to it, after selecting edit the option to edit details for the hero web-part is totally nonexistent. The only option I'm given is how many tiles I'd like displayed.

Am I the only one experiencing this or is this a know issue?
If there is a work around for this I would really appreciate some help. It just seems odd that you can edit details on the generated Hero web-part but not on one you add later on...

Please and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a new page in the communication site and add a hero web-part to it, i can choose "edit details" for the hero web-part, from there i can add images, texts and URLs for links:

[image]

After you add a hero web-part in a new page, make sure you choose "select link" to set a link, then you can see "edit details".

Use the Hero web part for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-hero-web-part-d57f449b-19a0-4b0d-8ce3-be5866430645

Comment: Is there anything update?

Answer (score 0):

We added a text web part under the hero web part and moved the description there.  Then changed the hero web part from layers to tiles.